# how to rank 3 highest value for each date

Tags: sqlite

i am new to sqlite, trying to solve how to only rank 3 highest value for each days

Table : price

### Date         | Name | value1 |

21-08-2018 |   A |     100

21-08-2018  |  B  |    90

21-08-2018  |  C  |    80

21-08-2018  |  D  |    70

21-08-2018  |  E  |    60

21-08-2018  |  F   |   50

22-08-2018  |  B   |   99

22-08-2018  |  A   |   88

22-08-2018  |  D   |   77

22-08-2018  |  C   |   66

22-08-2018  |  E   |   55

22-08-2018  |  F   |   44

23-08-2018  |  D   |   90

23-08-2018  |  A    |  80

23-08-2018  |  B   |   70

23-08-2018  |  C   |   80

23-08-2018  |  F   |   70

23-08-2018  |  E   |   60

i'am expecting the result like below

### Date         | Name | value1 |

21-08-2018  |  A  |    100

21-08-2018  |  B   |   90

21-08-2018  |  C   |   80

22-08-2018  |  B    |  99

22-08-2018  |  A    |  88

22-08-2018  |  D    |  77

23-08-2018   | D     | 90

23-08-2018  |  A    |  80

23-08-2018  |  B    |  70

i've tried
select *, max (value1)
from price
group by (date)

but only show one line, already tried using TOP3, but only show 3 from lots of row,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Sqlite 3.25 or newer, window functions make it easy:

```
WITH ranked AS (SELECT date, name, value1
                     , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY value1 DESC) AS rank
                FROM price)
SELECT date, name, value1
FROM ranked
WHERE rank <= 3
ORDER BY date, rank;
```

gives

```
date        name        value1    
----------  ----------  ----------
21-08-2018  A           100       
21-08-2018  B           90        
21-08-2018  C           80        
22-08-2018  B           99        
22-08-2018  A           88        
22-08-2018  D           77        
23-08-2018  D           90        
23-08-2018  A           80        
23-08-2018  C           80
```

This will potentially return more than three rows per date in case of duplicate `value1` figures causing ties - use `row_number()` instead of `rank()` for only ever at most three.

Comment: You should also strongly consider using an ISO-8601 format like `YYYY-MM-DD` for your dates instead of `DD-MM-YYYY`. The former works with sqlite date and time functions and is meaningfully sortable unlike the way you have them now.

Comment: i've change date to ISO-8601 (using db browser) into TEXT, the result become YYYY_MM_DD, is it correct?

Comment: after using query, the result is not like i wanted, is it because of format i'm using, i'm using value format of "REAL"

Comment: @wikwik Dashes, not underscores, for dates. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html for examples. -- I used `INTEGER` with `value1` for testing, but `REAL` will work too. `TEXT` for `value1`, however, won't, because the string `'100'` compares less than the string `'90'`.

Comment: i'm using sqlite 3.19.3, i can't find ISO_8601 format when using db browser for sqlite (edit display format menu tab)

Comment: @wikwik I have no idea what 'db browser for sqlite' is, but see that earlier link and https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype for how sqlite handles dates and times.

Comment: Also note that if you're using an old version like 3.19, this answer won't work for it, because it requires a more current version of sqlite.